# Определить состояние приложения из сервиса

Tags: android, service

Как можно из сервиса определить, что приложение свёрнуто (в зависимости от этого приложение будет выполнять различные действия).

Comment: Уточните, пожалуйста, откуда Вы хотите определить состояние приложения: из Activity или Service?

Comment: Получается, что из Service

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во всех `Activity` Вашего приложения, в методах `onPause()` и `onResume()`, записывайте флаг состояния приложения в `SharedPreferences`, а в `Service` проверяйте этот флаг.

**Activity:**

```
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit().putBoolean("PROPERTY_TEMP_FOREGROUND", true).apply();
}

protected void onPause() {

    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit().putBoolean("PROPERTY_TEMP_FOREGROUND", false).apply();
    super.onPause();
}
```

**Service:**

```
boolean isActivityRunning = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getBoolean("PROPERTY_TEMP_FOREGROUND", false);
```

Comment: А если активити много? Ну допустим, получается алгоритм такой: флаг один, каждое активити включает/выключает этот флаг, последнее изменение будет говорить о состоянии всего приложения. Так?

Comment: Все верно. В данном случае проще все Activity приложения наследовать от некоторой базовой, в которой и прописать код сохранения состояния.

Comment: Интересное и простое решение, спасибо!